# How can I clear rails action cache? (Rails.cache.clear isn't working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, heroku

### How can I clear rails action cache without restarting the server?

I have a script that updates the Postgres database with new data. I'd like to clear all cached pages after the script completes. but I can't seem to get this to take effect without completely restarting the Heroku server

I have tried without success:

- `Rails.cache.clear => ["/app/tmp/cache/bootsnap-compile-cache", "/app/tmp/cache/bootsnap-load-path-cache"]`
- `rails tmp:cache:clear`
- `rails assets:clean`

config.cache_store is not set explicitly for production, (I've seen mixed information as to what cache is being used by default)

I have ensured that there is no caching in the browser (by disabling caching in dev tools and bypassing the service worker)

I'm using Heroku with ruby 2.5.3, rails 5.2.1.1, and actionpack-action_caching 1.2.0

##### How do I know it's not being cached at the database layer or with Fragment Caching?

I added logging to the action which only logs the first time a page is accessed after a restart

**Update:** I removed action caching and instead better optimized the SQL quarries by using eager loading.

### Update 2 (writing in retrospect)

I didn't properly understand how Heroku's dyno's work.

Heroku spines up new VM's (dynos) when using [`heroku run bash`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno), causing any cache clearing not to affect the webserver running on the existing dyno. To ssh into running dynos you'll want to use [`heroku ps:exec`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec)

Comment: I wonder if this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Can you explain more about how you came to be certain that you need to clear the cache?

Comment: I have a 400 line update script (with more than 20 methods), it destroys 5 database tables and imports fresh data into these tables. After I added action caching, I realized that the script doesn't take effect until the server is restarted.

Comment: @AryeEidelman There are 3 possibilities; First one is, you are using in memory cache. In this case, even though you call `Rails.cache.clear` it shouldn't clear the cache because your script and Rails application runs in different processes and each process has it's own heap. Second one is, you are using file store as cache store. In this case, you should make sure your script is in the same machine with your Rails application, otherwise it only removes local cache files. Third one is, you are using different cache stores for your Rails application and your cleanup script.

Comment: @foo-bar-zoo thanks for the insight. As hazhir-derakhshi and others told me this should be using memory cache. So I'll add a clear cache button to the admin dashboard, that'll run Rails.cache.clear on the same process as the server. And see if that works.

Comment: Or I could have ssh'ed into the dyno and cleared the cache that way. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec

Answer (score 2):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/96dee0e7e5a8dd6ce42999b13d0bd0623073e229/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environments/production.rb.tt#L70), default cache store in production is mem_cache_store. Therefore, you should be able to clear it in different ways, without restarting the sever. Maciej Mensfeld wrote a [blog](https://mensfeld.pl/2013/04/clear-memcached-without-restart-with-ruby-and-capistrano-rake-task/) about these ways. I personally use `flush_all` command in the cache server if `Rails.cache.clear` does not make effect.